# ILMerge and Project References

Tags: .net, assemblies, ilmerge

I have a VS solution (.sln) that has the following structure.

- Project A
- Project B (contains reference to Project A as well as references to 3rd party assemblies like NHibernate, StructureMap, etc)

I want to use ILMerge to roll the 3rd party assemblies into the ProjectB.dll.  However, I don't want to merge ProjectA.

I've used the procedure highlighted [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx).  This has worked seamlessly for me regarding the merging of the third party assemblies.  However, I'm still getting this error when building ProjectB:

An exception occurred during merging:
  Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: ProjectA.

I'm not explicitly specifying that ProjectA be merged.  In other words, I don't say true for this project.  How do I get IlMerge to ignore ProjectA?  By the way, ProjectA is a project reference, not a direct assembly reference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use the `/lib` argument for ILMerge, passing the directory containing ProjectA.dll.

Specifically (assuming ProjectB's target platform is the .NET 4.0 client profile):

```
ILMerge.exe /out:MasterDll.dll
            /targetplatform:v4,"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client"
            /lib:ProjectA\bin\Release
            ProjectB\bin\Release\ProjectB.dll
            Libraries\NHibernate\NHibernate.dll
            Libraries\StructureMap\StructureMap.dll
            ...
```

Answer (score -1):

For 4.0 just use:

/targetplatform:v4,"%ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0"